# DynamoDB Nested Query

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

```
{
"agent": "testing",
"content": "no content",
"created_at": "2018-08-14T14:52:50.622+05:30",
"event_type": "KYC_FOLLOWUP",
"generated_by": "AGENT",
"interacting_service": "KYC",
"order_id": "456",
"serviceData": {
    "documentName": "PAN",
    "status": "REJECTED"
   },
"user_id": "123",
"user_identifier": "790"
}
```

I have a Model like above. I need aws cli query between any two dates for which serviceData status is REJECTED. I have interacting_service as my hashKey and range key is created_at. Can someone help me with this

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i got the soln thanks